# Get all selected checkboxes from listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I'm using a ListBox control into my application. But when i am going to get All the selected values it returns false while i'd checked some values .

```html
<asp:ListBox ID="lstSelectServices" Class="form-control lstSelectService" SelectionMode="Multiple"  runat="server"  data-placeholder="Select Service"></asp:ListBox>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
           $(function () { 
              $('.lstSelectService').multiselect({ 
                  includeSelectAllOption: true,  
                 buttonClass: 'btn btn-default w-100 btn-multisetect'   
            });    
       });   
    });
   </script>
```

Here is code to Bind the ListBox

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["sub"]);

      IndexRepository obj = new IndexRepository();
      ds = obj.SelectSubServices(id);
      lstSelectServices.DataSource = ds;
      lstSelectServices.DataTextField = "name";
      lstSelectServices.DataValueField = "id";
      lstSelectServices.DataBind();
```

Here is code to Get selected values from ListBox

```
foreach(ListItem item in lstSelectServices.Items)
       {
           if(item.Selected)
           {
               model.ServiceNeed += item.Text + ",";
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved as the dropdown did not have the postback attribute set as True.
And I was not using the `!IsPostBack` on page load.